# Creating indefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to create indefinite matrix for testing solver, which I am currently developing. What would be best way to proceed? Or what would be recommended topic to take a look at ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A $n\times n$ matrix is indefinite if there are both positive and negative eigenvalues.
The entries on the diagonal of a diagonal matrix are its eigenvalues.

So the simplest matrix is probably
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
-1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
For higher dimensions just fill up the diagonal, as you need.

Answer (score 0):

A simple course of action is to pick any unital lower triangular matrix $L$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ with nonnegative diagonal entries and as many zeros on the diagonal as you like. The compute $A = LDL^T$ and feed it to your solver.